# How to create new column with pasted values of select colnames from lookup table

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a new column in one dataframe (named 'input') that takes, as values, colname(s) from another dataframe (named 'Lookup') based on the values within the relevant columns in the lookup table.  Here are some fake data representing the two tables:

## CREATE FAKE LOOKUP TABLE

```
Drugs <- c("amitriptyline", "aripiprazole", "asenapine", "bupropion", "carbamazepine", "citalopram","clomipramine", "clozapine", "desipramine")
CYP1A1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Ind",NA)
CYP1A2 <- c("S_Inh",NA,NA,"S","S_Inh_Ind","Inh","S","Ind",NA)
CYP1B1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Ind",NA)
CYP2A6 <- c(NA,NA,NA,"S","Ind",NA,NA,"S","Inh")
CYP2A13 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
CYP2B6 <- c("S",NA,NA,"S_Inh", "S_Ind","Inh",NA,NA,"Ind")
CYP2C8 <- c("S_Inh",NA,NA,"S","S_Ind",NA,NA,"S",NA)
CYP2C9 <- c("S",NA,NA,"S","Ind",NA,NA,"S_Inh",NA)
LookUp <- data.frame(Drugs, CYP1A1,CYP1A2, CYP1B1, CYP2A6,CYP2A13,CYP2B6,CYP2C8,CYP2C9)

LookUp
#           Drugs CYP1A1    CYP1A2 CYP1B1 CYP2A6 CYP2A13 CYP2B6 CYP2C8 CYP2C9
# 1 amitriptyline   <NA>     S_Inh   <NA>   <NA>      NA      S  S_Inh      S
# 2  aripiprazole   <NA>      <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 3     asenapine   <NA>      <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 4     bupropion   <NA>         S   <NA>      S      NA  S_Inh      S      S
# 5 carbamazepine   <NA> S_Inh_Ind   <NA>    Ind      NA  S_Ind  S_Ind    Ind
# 6    citalopram   <NA>       Inh   <NA>   <NA>      NA    Inh   <NA>   <NA>
# 7  clomipramine   <NA>         S   <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 8     clozapine    Ind       Ind    Ind      S      NA   <NA>      S  S_Inh
# 9   desipramine   <NA>      <NA>   <NA>    Inh      NA    Ind   <NA>   <NA>
```

## CREATE FAKE INPUT TABLE

```
input <- data.frame(rowID=c(1:4), Drug=Drugs[c(1,3,4,9)])
input
#   rowID          Drug
# 1     1 amitriptyline
# 2     2     asenapine
# 3     3     bupropion
# 4     4  desipramine
```

I would like to create a new column in input, input$metabCYPs, that is a comma-separated string of all column names from the lookup table in which the corresponding column value contains an 'S' for the particular drug.
I thought one component might be to identify the set of all 'S'-containing values in any column:

```
subsVals <- c("S_Inh", "S", "S_Ind", "S_Inh_Ind")
```

But, I can't figure out how to use this to generate the desired output:

```
output
    #   rowID          Drug   metabCYPs
    # 1     1 amitriptyline   CYP1A2, CYP2B6, CYP2C8, CYP2C9
    # 2     2     asenapine   
    # 3     3     bupropion   CYP1A2, CYP2A6, CYP2B6, CYP2C8, CYP2C9
    # 4     4   desipramine
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with `dplyr` and `reshape2` packages,

```
#First you add stringsAsFactors = FALSE in your dataframes,

LookUp <- data.frame(Drugs, CYP1A1,CYP1A2, CYP1B1, CYP2A6,CYP2A13,CYP2B6,CYP2C8,CYP2C9, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
input <- data.frame(rowID=c(1:4), Drug=Drugs[c(1,3,4,9)], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

melt(LookUp, id.vars = 'Drugs', na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(Drugs) %>% 
  summarise(metabCYPs = toString(variable[grepl('S', value)])) %>%   
  left_join(input, ., by = c('Drug' = 'Drugs'))

#  rowID          Drug                              metabCYPs
#1     1 amitriptyline         CYP1A2, CYP2B6, CYP2C8, CYP2C9
#2     2     asenapine                                   <NA>
#3     3     bupropion CYP1A2, CYP2A6, CYP2B6, CYP2C8, CYP2C9
#4     4   desipramine
```

To create the rest of the columns then just add them in `summarise`, i.e.

```
melt(LookUp, id.vars = 'Drugs', na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(Drugs) %>% 
   summarise(metabCYPs = toString(variable[grepl('S', value)]), 
             with_Ihn = toString(variable[grepl('Inh', value)]), 
             with_Ind = toString(variable[grepl('Ind', value)])) %>% 
   left_join(input, ., by = c('Drug' = 'Drugs'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since the values of variables in data frames `LookUp` and `input` are the same and additionally, there seems to be no duplicates in `LookUp$Drugs` and `input$Drug`, it would be wise to join them but prior you need to packages: `data.table` and `dplyr`:

```
install.packages(c("data.table", "dplyr"))
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
```

Let's join the tables:

```
output <- merge(input, LookUp, by.x = "Drug", by.y = "Drugs", all.x = T)

           Drug rowID CYP1A1 CYP1A2 CYP1B1 CYP2A6 CYP2A13 CYP2B6 CYP2C8 CYP2C9
1 amitriptyline     1   <NA>  S_Inh   <NA>   <NA>      NA      S  S_Inh      S
2     asenapine     2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3     bupropion     3   <NA>      S   <NA>      S      NA  S_Inh      S      S
4   desipramine     4   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    Inh      NA    Ind   <NA>   <NA>
```

Now you have all the needed columns in one table. As for the variable itself:

```
output$metabCYPs <- output[,3:10] %>%
  apply(1, paste0) %>% 
  setdiff("NA") %>% 
  paste0(collapse = ", ")
```

The first line chooses the columns 3 to 10 from `output` data frame, the second one pastes columns by row. The third one removes `NA` values, and the last one adds commas between values. You may remove the redundant variables 3-10 by:

```
output[,3:10] <- NA
```

Voila!

Comment: Thanks, kaksat. This creates an output column with the values from the lookup table rather than the column names.  It also generated the same values for each row in the output table rather than the values corresponding to the correct drug.  However, it appears that Sotos solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` and `reshape` bug me... Here's another idea that uses an implicit loop over the Drug Var:

```
metabCYPs <- sapply(LookUp$Drugs, function(x) paste0(names(LookUp[which(LookUp$Drugs == x), grepl("S", LookUp[which(LookUp$Drugs == x), setdiff(names(LookUp), "Drugs")])]), collapse = ", "))
output <- data.frame(input, metabCYPs=metabCYPs[match(input$Drugs, names(metabCYPs))])
```